# can't download graphql schema from server using apollo cli

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server, codegen

I made sure I have the same version of graphql in both server and client but sill getting error .
this is the script I'm running :

```
    "schema:download": "apollo --schema:download --endpoint=http://localhost:4000/graphql"
```

I'm getting this error :

```
 Error: Cannot use GraphQLSchema "{ __validationErrors: undefined, description: undefined, 
extensions: undefined, astNode: undefined, extensionASTNodes: undefined, _queryType: Query, 
_mutationType: Mutation, _subscriptionType: null, _directives: [@cacheControl, @skip, @include, 
@deprecated], _typeMap: { Query: Query, User: User, ID: ID, String: String, Mutation: Mutation, 
Boolean: Boolean, __Schema: __Schema, __Type: __Type, __TypeKind: __TypeKind, __Field: __Field, 
__InputValue: __InputValue, __EnumValue: __EnumValue, __Directive: __Directive, 
__DirectiveLocation: __DirectiveLocation, CacheControlScope: CacheControlScope, Upload: Upload, 
Int: Int }, _subTypeMap: {}, _implementationsMap: {} }" from another module or realm.

Ensure that there is only one instance of "graphql" in the node_modules
directory. If different versions of "graphql" are the dependencies of other
relied on modules, use "resolutions" to ensure only one version is installed.

https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions

Duplicate "graphql" modules cannot be used at the same time since different
versions may have different capabilities and behavior. The data from one
version used in the function from another could produce confusing and
spurious results.
```